# jest: import statement outside a module for common sub module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I have looked at all the answers to this error but none work for me.

In my case I have a bunch of **common** code which is in a sub-module used in a few reactjs projects.

As such

folders are like this

```
project1
project2
common
```

It all works well running in each of the projects but jest tests fail with

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
  1 | import { connect } from 'react-redux'
> 2 | import { getDataCollectorToken } from 'common/src/shared/redux/datapoints/thunks';
    | ^
```

Ive tried to add
"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["common/**"
But to no avail

Any advice as to how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mapping for common module with [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring)

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ....,
    ....,
    '^@common/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/path-to-your-common-module',
    
  },
```

Also make sure you are transforming `common` module & adding it in `transformIgnorePatterns` config as well.

```
"transform": {
  "path-to-your-common-module/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "common"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "path-to-your-common-module/(?!common/.*)"
]
```

Comment: problem is <rootDir> is: /Volumes/Untitled/project1 and it doesn't like path of ../<rooDir>/common